# Python Dash nested html ul list

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I want to create a dash html component to show a nested collapsable tree of a certain depth. I have an html div and I want this to contain a root `html.Ul`. 
For each depth I have a labels list and a list of list with the correspondant subtrees, that are the labels for the next depth.

```
html.Ul([
    html.Li([
              'subtotal1',
              html.Ul([html. Li([...] ) ]),
              'subtotal2', 
              html. Ul([html. Li([...]) ] )             
    ] ) 
])
```

this is my code for one depth:

```
html_lists = []
for i in reversed(range(1,2)):
    html_ul_list = html.Ul([])
    pp.pprint(fp_data[i], indent = 4)

    for cat in fp_data[i]['unique']:
        html_ul_list.children.append(
            html.Li([cat,
                     html.Ul(
                         [html.Li(fp_data[i]['lists'][idx]) for idx in range(0,len(fp_data[i]['lists']))]

                         )
                     ])
            )

    html_lists.append(html_ul_list)
```

where

```
fp_data[0]['unique'] = ['Total']
fp_data[0]['lists'] = [['Total|Shape','Total|FirstOrder']]

fp_data[1]['unique'] = ['Total|Shape','Total|FirstOrder']
fp_data[1]['lists'] = [['Total|Shape|Mean','Total|Shape|Kurtosis'], 
['Total|FirstOrder|Mean','Total|FirstOrder|GrayLevel']]

fp_data[2]['unique'] = ['Total|Shape|Mean','Total|Shape|Kurtosis','Total|FirstOrder|Mean','Total|FirstOrder|GrayLevel']

fp_data[2]['lists'] = [
['Total|Shape|Mean|x','Total|Shape|Mean|y'], 
['Total|Shape|Kurstosis|x','Total|Shape|Kurstosis|y'], 
['Total|FirstOrder|Mean|x','Total|FirstOrder|Mean|y'],
['Total|FirstOrder|Graylevel|x','Total|FirstOrder|GrayLevel|y'],
]
```

Edit: more trials with the data provided:

```
    html_lists = []
    for i in reversed(range(0,3)):
        html_ul_list = html.Ul([],style = {'text-align':'left', 'marginLeft':'5px'})
        pp.pprint(fp_data[i], indent = 4)

        for idxcat,cat in enumerate(fp_data[i]['unique']):
           print('idxcat',idxcat)
           print(fp_data[i]['lists'])
            html_ul_list.children.append(
               html.Li([cat,
                         html.Ul(
                             [html.Li(fp_data[i]['lists'][idxcat][idx]) for idx in range(0,len(fp_data[i]['lists'][idxcat]))]

                             )
                         ])
                )

        html_lists.append(html_ul_list)
```

[image]

Comment: can you show any example or link?

Comment: Yes,  I am trying to fill this one with python data: http://code.iamkate.com/javascript/collapsible-lists/

Comment: You want to create UI dynamically using python right.

Comment: Exactly!  I can do that hardcoding some depths but I don't know how to translate the structures I have to a nested html.Ul/Li

Comment: This is what i want to traslate          Depth 1
Labels ['Total'] 
Lists [['Total|shape','Total|firstOrder' ]] 

Depth 2
Labels ['Total|shape','Total|firstOrder' ]
Lists[[total|shape|mean, total|shape|kurtosis], [Total|firstorder|graylevel,... ]]

Comment: can you add some code snippet?

Comment: Hey Last thing I want to know that what the is input format for method.

Comment: Is a lists of dicts,  one for each depth.  Fp_data[depth]['unique'] is a list of labels  and fp_data[depth] ['lists']  is a list of lists where each inner list has correspondence with the elements in the list of labels.

Comment: @CharlesMartin Share the data that needs to be run through the for loop, it can be sample data too!

Comment: I can't share that since it is too large. for the third level. I will add to my problem a formatted example.